# django: naming files, dirs, classes, etc

Tags: python, django

django 2.0

python 3.6.3

Hi,

I have stubbed my toe on django.  I have seen that models can be split out into individual files a la:

```
    |-- models
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- Profile.py
```

I have also tried to do the same thing with views and forms.  I ran into the case where I was importing a model and a view where the underlying file had the same name:

```
    from models import Profile
    from views import Profile
```

but the code got confused over which "Profile" I was talking about.  I decided to rename the files

```
    |-- models
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- m_profile.py

    |-- views
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- v_profile.py
```

then do

```
    from models.m_profile import Profile
    from views.v_profile import Profile
```

but now the migrations are messed up -- I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`.  Is there a better way to handle these things?

Comment: Well renaming the modules like that won't in any way help with the naming conflict between classes. Why don't you just rename your view class to something like ProfileView?

Comment: Thanks, will try that.  I just assumed that the ambiguity would be dealt with in context.

Comment: I don't know what that means. You can't have two things with the same name in the same place; if you import two things called Profile into the same file, the second import will overwrite the first.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Python and other languages I use enforce more of a dotted name construct instead of `from x import y`.  These languages would force one to say something like `models.Profile.methodName()`. cheers

Comment: Just alias them during import; no need to rename them in their own modules. E.g., `from .models.m_profile import Profile; from .views.v_profile import Profile as ProfileView`. (The dot in from of models and views makes them relative imports, i.e., keeping things within the package/app. Provided the code importing them is also in the package/app.)

Comment: Cool.  Thanks, I'll try that.  Didn't know about aliasing